# Why does sytemd-analyze underreports boot time?

Tags: systemd

I installed 15.04 mainly to speed up my shutdown times from 15+ seconds to much less: now my laptop shuts down in three seconds, which is alright.

As systemd offers tools to analyze and speed up boot process like `systemd-analyze`, I played with it (found `kexec-tools` package along the way) and by disabling `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` and `privoxy.service` (I was not using the latter actually), I manged to get to here:

```
 Startup finished in 3.571s (firmware) + 3.404s (loader) + 2.054s (kernel) + 2.470s (userspace) = 11.501s
```

However, when I actually measure with my phone the bootup time till the moment unity desktop, launcher and the top bar actually appear from the moment I press the power button, it is about 14-15 seconds. Where are the 3 seconds lost? Does systemd cheat a bit:-)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the thing you call `boot-exec` ?

Comment: Eh, a mental typo (corrected in the question) I meant kexec, the ability to skip BIOS and GRUB2 during rebooting. It more than halves my reboot time, as can be seen from the output of `systemd-analyze`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but `systemd-analyze` records time until the **default target** has been reached which is *graphical.target*.

You can look at `systemd-analyze critical-chain` output to make this apparent.

This certainly means it records time until lightdm (or your dm) has been launched and not after. Which means it did not take into account the 3s that unity needs to open your session (I'm guessing you are using auto-login).

Comment: I see, yes, I am using autologin. That might be it that it would take 12 seconds to lightdm prompt (but does not unity start in the background when lightdm prompt is shown? when I type my password, it seems to show immediately, if I remember correctly).